# Python var inside selenium driver.execute_script

Tags: javascript, python, arguments, robotframework, keyword

I'm creating some custom keywords for robotframework and I'm stuck on a problem.

I've got the following keyword that is working if I give javascript an argument, for example:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary

class roboJSlib:

    @keyword('Checkbox select')
    def check(self, arg):
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')._current_browser()
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('preventivo_privacy_accetto_informative').click()")
```

I want the script to get "arg" as id, which is defined in robotframework as an argument.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
@keyword('Checkbox select')
    def check(self, arg):
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')._current_browser()
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('"+arg+"').click()")
```

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass arguments to `execute_script` method and refer to them in JavaScript using `arguments[x]` syntax, so in your case it would be:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary

class roboJSlib:

    @keyword('Checkbox select')
    def check(self, arg):
        driver = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')._current_browser()
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(arguments[0]).click()", arg)
```